# How to delete the snapshots with a tag by setting the retention period

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have a script to delete the snapshots after a retention period. It works good and deletes the snapshots that passes the retention period. But I have to filter it with tags. Means only the snapshots that has a particular tag should be deleted.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import datetime

# Set the global variables
globalVars  = {}
globalVars['Owner']                 = "Cloud"
globalVars['Environment']           = "Test"
globalVars['REGION_NAME']           = "ap-south-1"
globalVars['tagName']               = "Testing"
globalVars['findNeedle']            = "DeleteOn"
globalVars['RetentionDays']         = "1"
globalVars['tagsToExclude']         = "Do-Not-Delete"

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

"""
This function looks at *all* snapshots that have a "DeleteOn" tag containing
the current day formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. This function should be run at least
daily.
"""

def janitor_for_snapshots():
    account_ids = list()
    account_ids.append( boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account') )

    snap_older_than_RetentionDays = ( datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days= int(globalVars['RetentionDays'])) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    delete_today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    tag_key = 'tag:' + globalVars['findNeedle']
    filters = [{'Name': tag_key, 'Values': [delete_today]},]

    # filters={ 'tag:' + config['tag_name']: config['tag_value'] }

    # Get list of Snaps with Tag 'globalVars['findNeedle']'
    snaps_to_remove = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids,Filters=filters)

    # Get the snaps that doesn't have the tag and are older than Retention days
    all_snaps = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids)
    for snap in all_snaps['Snapshots']:
        if snap['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') <= snap_older_than_RetentionDays:
            snaps_to_remove['Snapshots'].append(snap)

    snapsDeleted = {'Snapshots': []}

    for snap in snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']:
        try:
            ec2_client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap['SnapshotId'])
            snapsDeleted['Snapshots'].append({'Description': snap['Description'], 'SnapshotId': snap['SnapshotId'], 'OwnerId': snap['OwnerId']})
        except ClientError as e:
            if "is currently in use by" in str(e):
                print("Snapshot {} is part of an AMI".format(snap.get('SnapshotId')))

    snapsDeleted['Status']='{} Snapshots were Deleted'.format( len(snaps_to_remove['Snapshots']))

    return snapsDeleted

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return janitor_for_snapshots()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lambda_handler(None, None)
```

I want to delete the snapshots only with "DeleteOn" Tag. But this script deletes all that passed the retention period. Its not checking the Tag part.

Please check and help on this. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to fix the code so that it only deletes snapshots that:

- Have the given tag, *AND*
- Have passed the retention period

then look closely at your code.

This part:

```
# Get list of Snaps with Tag 'globalVars['findNeedle']'
snaps_to_remove = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids,Filters=filters)
```

is obtaining a list of snapshots by tag. Great!

Then this part:

```
# Get the snaps that doesn't have the tag and are older than Retention days
all_snaps = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids)
for snap in all_snaps['Snapshots']:
    if snap['StartTime'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') <= snap_older_than_RetentionDays:
        snaps_to_remove['Snapshots'].append(snap)
```

is getting a NEW list of snapshots and checking the retention.

Then, the resulting `snaps_to_remove` contains the results from BOTH of them.

You will need to combine your logic so it is only adding snaps that meet both criteria rather than compiling the list of snapshots separately.

Comment: You are 100% right.. Now the final list has combination of both.. This is where I am stuck.. Can you please help me combine the logic.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow users are happy to assist with questions, but please do not ask other people to write code for you. Please try it yourself. If you have any specific problems, feel free to ask a Question.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein.. I fixed it :)

Comment: Good work! Sorry for seeming harsh, but now you've gained new skills. :)